# How do i make an exit button for my text based game in Python?

Tags: python

i wanted to make my code in a `while` loop and when the user inputs "end", the program closes. I did it like this

```
T = True
while T:
    startInput = input()
    # insert code
while True:
    if startInput == "end" or startInput == "End":
    T = False
    break
```

The problem is that it doesn't work.

Comment: Try removing the second `while True` and indenting `T = False`, 
  `break` these two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
T = True
while T:
    startInput = input()
    # insert code
    if startInput == "end" or startInput == "End":
        T = False  
        break
```

The problem was you were running the first loop and it never runs the second one so it can never exucute that code and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3.8 above you  can use like this :

```
T = True
while (startInput := input()) not in ["end","END"]:   
    # insert code
T=False
```